# Unable to load local json file from assets in Flutter Package project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, dart-packages

I was working on building a Package project in Flutter and hence I have to add lot of .svg image files and local config.json file from Assets for the Package. But I can able to load the .svg files, but it was throwing error for loading .json file.

I have filed a bug on the github flutter repo, please check the below link for further details. Please do the needful.

[Unable to load local json file from "assets" folder in Flutter Package project](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106847#issue-1289553394)

Comment: You need to declare this file as an asset in your pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - assets/JsonConfig/test.json
```

pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the path with the following format `packages/<yourpackagename>/<path to your file>` such as below

```
String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('packages/yourpackagename/assets/yourfile.json');
```

Comment: Will surely try this solution and update you asap. Thanks @adee alamsz